# C++ calculate values dynamically like in a spreadsheet?

Tags: c++, dynamic

Is it possible to for values to dynamically be calculated in C++ like in a spreadsheet (in reaction to another variable been changed) ?

For example:

```
int x;
y = 2 * x;
cin >> x;
cout << y;
```

I want to make it so that I can modify `x` repeatedly and `cout << y` will show the recalculated value, instead of having to close the program or endl and input again to enter a different value of x. (See picture)

[image: spreadsheet example]

Comment: The language doesn't do this, I'm afraid. You will have to place the operation after you receive input and re-run it every time you receive input. A loop and possibly a function will help here.

Comment: @user4581301: It is possible, it's called reactive programming.

Comment: I stand corrected. What I should have said is this doesn't come out of the box in C++.

Comment: What kind of program are you designing ?

Comment: Without additional explanation and motivation, your question is unclear and too broad. Please **edit your question** to improve it a lot.

Comment: I bet Microsoft is using their own VC++ compiler when creating Excel. So the short answer must be **Yes** (but using a bit more code).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No coding can be done in this way. When the variable is defined, free space is given from the memory, but no arithmetic processing can be done because no value assignment is made.

Answer (score 0):

You really want to embed an [interpreter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpreter_(computing)) in your program. You could embed [Lua](http://lua.org/), [Guile](https://www.gnu.org/software/guile/), etc...

A [spreadsheet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spreadsheet) like Excel is an interpreter of some ad-hoc [lazy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_evaluation), event-driven, functional programming language with a nice table-driven GUI. Some spreadsheets like [Libreoffice](http://libreoffice.org/) or [Gnumeric](http://www.gnumeric.org/) are [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software), so you can study their source code (and perhaps adapt or extend it to your needs). And with some effort (perhaps a few months), you can code a simple spreadsheet program (use [Qt](http://qt.io/) for the [GUI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUI) part). There are many free software spreadsheet-like programs available on [github](http://github.com/).

Otherwise, write your interpreter or evaluator yourself. Define your language and its syntax (using [EBNF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Backus%E2%80%93Naur_form) notation) and [semantics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantics_(computer_science)). [Parse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing) some syntax into an [AST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree), have some notion of *environment* mapping variables to values, and code your evaluator. Given an environment and the AST of some expression, your evaluator will (recursively) compute the value of the given expression in the given environment. You could even consider using some [JIT compilation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just-in-time_compilation) library (like [GCCJIT](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/jit/)) to generate machine code related to each expression.

Reading the [Dragon Book](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compilers:_Principles,_Techniques,_and_Tools), [*Programming Language Pragmatics*](https://www.cs.rochester.edu/~scott/pragmatics/), [*Lisp In Small Pieces*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lisp_in_Small_Pieces) will be helpful to design then implement such an interpreter (or simple spreadsheet).

Perhaps you simply need to accept [plugins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plug-in_(computing)) to your software.

See also [this answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/360106/40065) to a related question.

Don't forget that C++ variables are only known to the compiler. During execution, they are just memory locations.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. But You have to program it.
The most simple version is to use a lambda:

```
int main()
{
    int y;
    int x;
    auto updateYfromX = [ & ]()
    {
        y = x * 2;
    };

    std::cin >> x;
    updateYfromX();

    std::cout << '\n' << x << ':' << y << '\n';
}
```

But the problem here is that you have to remember to call the update function each time x is change;

So what now?
Now you need to harness the power of C++ and create a class that automatically reacts to changes in it's value.

Here is such a class `ReactOnChangeInt`.
It takes an additional parameter, a function, which is called every time a new value is assigned to it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

class ReactOnChangeInt
{
    int value;
    const std::function<void(const int)> onChangeAction;
public:
    ReactOnChangeInt( const std::function<void(const int)> action )
        : value{}
        , onChangeAction( action )
    { }
    ReactOnChangeInt(const int i, const std::function<void (const int)> action)
        : value(i)
        , onChangeAction( action )
    {}

    int operator= (const int i)
    {
        value = i;
        onChangeAction(value);
        return value;
    }

    operator int() const
    {
        return value;
    }

    friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& out, ReactOnChangeInt m)
    {
        out << m.value;
        return out;
    }
    friend std::istream& operator >> ( std::istream& in, ReactOnChangeInt& m )
    {
        int i;
        in >> i;
        m = i;
        return in;
    }
};
```

You can use it so:

```
int main()
{
    int y;
    ReactOnChangeInt x ( [ & ]( const int val )
    {
        y = val * 2;
    } );

    std::cin >> x;

    std::cout << '\n' << x << ':' << y << '\n';
}
```

The next step from this is to create a generalized version of the class (using templates) so you can use any type (not just `int`).